# Porting C Code to C# / dereferencing a pointer

Tags: c#, c

How would I port this piece of C Code to C#? It is a UPC Key Recovery Tool.

`hv` is a `uint32_t` array with 4 elements. `h1` is a `uint8_t` array with 16 elements

```
uint32_t hv[4] = ...
uint8_t h1[16] = ...

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    hv[i] = *(uint16_t *)(h1 + i*2);
}
```

While this is valid C code I cannot seem to port this to C# without it giving me errors. Does anybody have an idea what I could do?

I've tried declaring `hv` as a uint array and `h1` as a byte array.

Comment: You'll be wanting `System.BitConverter.ToUInt16`  The BitConverter class will be helpful in conversion of any code containing a pointer cast.

Comment: Don't think about it at the level of pointers. **Say at a high level what the program fragment does**.  "I have an array of 4 uints and an array of 16 bytes; I wish to write four uints to the array such that..."

Comment: Now you've written a specification.  Implement that specification in C# using the idioms of C#.

Comment: The full original c code can be found on https://haxx.in/upc_keys.c

Comment: @EricLippert: I wonder how many people would dare give this a try if the loop body were the equivalent `i[hv] = i[(uint16_t*)h1];`

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yeah, people just shouldn't do that. :-)

Comment: @EricLippert: But rumor has it that C# coders understand subscripting better than dereferencing and pointer arithmetic  ;)   Do you happen to know if Coverity checkers (for C and C++) flag subscript operand reversal?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I don't recall having seen that one, but the number of C checkers is *huge*. I would be surprised if it was not there, but I have no specific knowledge of it.

Comment: The notion that this is "valid" C code is suspect; it depends for example on the byte array being in a particular endianness.

Comment: this is the type of code that looks *so sweet* when converted to `Span<T>` :)

Comment: @MarcGravell: For some reason they're pulling 4 ushorts out of an array of 16 bytes.  Who can say why?

Comment: @MarcGravell: The type coming out is `uint16_t` and the stride is `sizeof (uint16_t)`. Seems ok. It's being stored to a new array which has a wider type than needed.

Comment: @EricLippert: The code shows another loop five lines below this one, that pulls out the other half: `hv[i] = *(uint16_t *)(h1 + 8 + i*2);`

Comment: @BenVoigt: Well that explains it.  Though it never ceases to amaze me how awful this sort of C code is. The original author could have written `uint16_t * ps = (uint16_t*)h1; for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) hv[i] = ps[i];` which is far easier to understand and less prone to error.

Comment: @EricLippert: Interesting thing is that the code in the original source is not "valid C code" as the question claims.  In fact it violates the strict aliasing rule and has potential alignment problems.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I learned a long time ago that what people mean when they say "valid C code" is "works on my machine".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially:

```
        ushort[] hv = new ushort[4];
        byte[] h1 = new byte[16];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            // note: this call is CPU-endian; if your data is not CPU-endian,
            // you will need to write a known-endian op - aka "shift" and "or"
            hv[i] = BitConverter.ToUInt16(h1, i * 2);
        }
```

Although I wonder if a blit might be more appropriate.

Note that you can also use `unsafe` C# code to have *essentially the same code as the C code* (via `fixed`), and in the upcoming bits: this would be a good fit for `Span<T>` which allows for simple thunks between different `T`.

Comment: After some twinkling around, i got this almost finished, how would you port hv[i] = *(uint16_t *)(h1 + 8 + i*2); to C#?

Comment: @Varreza the `*(uint16_t *)` is the `BitConverter.ToUInt16`, where `h1` is the vector (array) and `8 + i*2` is the offset. So literally the only thing that changes is the second parameter to `ToUInt16`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Break it down.  What are we doing?  **Work from the semantic level, not from the level of pointers**.

- We have a byte array with some number of bytes.
- We take two bytes at a time and alias them as 16-bit unsigned integers
- We extract the 16-bit unsigned integer, convert it to a 32-bit unsigned integer, and assign that to an array element.

Now we have a specification. **Write a method for each interesting operation.** The only interesting operation is turning two bytes into one ushort; everything else is done for you by the compiler.

```
static ushort BytesToUshort(byte b1, byte b2)
{
   // You can implement this method
}
```

Great. Now we have a tool we can use.  What bytes do we want? The bytes at `i*2` and `i*2+1`.  So:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    hv[i] = BytesToUshort(h1[i*2], h1[i*2+1]);
}
```

And we're done.

Don't try to translate pointer manipulation code to C#; you can do it but it will not be good C# code. Write code that has the same effect but uses the conventions of C#.

A technique that might help is to rewrite the code so that it is less awful C code; this is terrible.  If you rewrote the original code into C like this first:

```
uint16_t *ps = (uint16_t*)h1;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  hv[i] = ps[i];
```

I daresay that it would have been a lot easier to understand conceptually what was going on here.

Comment: "Don't try to translate pointer manipulation code to C#" - agreed, but in the future: the new `Span<T>` stuff allows direct coercion of spans between different `T`, which makes this kind of stuff *so cute*, without needing any `unsafe`

Comment: @MarcGravell: Indeed, I agree. My intention here was to describe how to solve the general problem from first principles, rather than to solve the specific problem using cool new stuff that's not fully baked yet.

Comment: and it always impresses me how well you express that key aim - "write/ask what you're trying to do, not how you're trying to do it" - once you've done that: most things fade away into implementation minutae